# Applying conditions between columns in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server

```
Primary    Secondary
-----------------------------------
UST         MUN
Data        NULL
Tele        Data
Sun         Data
RMDS        Data
Data        NULL
Mor         NULL
UST         NULL
Data        Bridge
```

I want to check if values of "Secondary" is already in "primary" then it should come as "primary" but if it is not in "primary" values it must come under "Secondary" column only.

Here I want output as:

```
Primary  Secondary
------  -----------
UST      MUN
Data     Bridge
Tele
Sun
RMDS
Mor
```

Comment: Could you show us what have your tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of <a>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11302617/select-distinct-values-from-multiple-columns-in-same-table</a>

Comment: Could any one answer my question ?

Comment: i think the answer given is the correct one, did you try that?

Comment: I want to check if values of "Secondary" is already in "primary" then it should come as "primary" but if it is not in "primary" values it must come under "Secondary" column only. "i want this out put"

Comment: Primary  Secondary
------  -----------
UST      MUN
Data     Bridge
Tele
Sun
RMDS
Mor
Bridge

Comment: `bridge` is not in `primary`, but in your desired output in question it is under `primary`. ?

Comment: Sorry My bad ,Bridge must come under "secondary" as it was not in "primary" list.Is that possible?? how can i get output like this ?

Answer (score 1):

A `UNION` (rather that `UNION ALL`) will return all distinct values you require:

```sql
SELECT Primary
FROM MyTable

UNION

SELECT Secondary
FROM MyTable
WHERE Secondary IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thanks ,But Null value is also coming in output, but i do not want this

Comment: select *
from (select primaryFeed as feed from #feedinfo
union
select SecondaryFeed from #feedinfo) fedd
where feed is not null

Comment: Hey can you answer my above query ?

Comment: @Himani, I updated the query and added `WHERE Secondary IS NOT NULL`. Or, is it the case that you want the output in two columns?

Comment: This is fine, but if i want to add one more column in output as 'type' and it should output by checking ( 2 conditions , 1) if  2 col value is in 1st col then 'type' is 'primary' but 2) if  2nd col is not in 1st col then 'type' is secondary

Comment: Primary  type
------  -----------
UST      primary
Data     primary
Tele     primary
Sun      primary
RMDS     primary
Mor      primary
MUN      Secondary
Bridge   Secondary
                                                                                                                                    here MUN and Bridge were not in 1st col so they should come as secondary                                                                                                             i tried this:

Comment: select pri as feed,'type' = (case when sec not in (select distinct pri from #feedinfo ) then 'sec' else 'pri' end) from #feedinfo
union
select sec ,'type' = (case when sec in (select distinct pri from #feedinfo ) then 'pri' else null end) from #feedinfo

Answer (score 0):

Both rows in one output is not possible since you dont have the combining factor. How will the db know that `UST - MUN`  should come in same row and not `UST - Bridge` .

What you can get it in a two different outputs and build your programming logic around it.

For first row you can do :

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT t1.`primary` FROM tableName t1 
UNION
SELECT t1.`primary` FROM tableName t1 
INNER JOIN tableName t2 ON t1.primary = t2.`secondry`
) AS test1
```

And for second you can do :

```
SELECT DISTINCT t2.`secondry` FROM tableName t1 
RIGHT JOIN tableName t2 ON t1.primary = t2.`secondry` 
WHERE  t1.primary IS  NULL AND t2.secondry IS NOT NULL
```