# How can I get count of unique values across two columns in a table?

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct, multiple-columns

I have a table with column1 and column2 among other columns?

I need a count of unique values across all rows taken from column1 and column2.
Possible query:
select count(*) from
(   (select distinct column1 from table1) UNION
    (select distinct column2 from table1)    );

I also need a count of unique values across all rows as per below :-
"column1" + "-" + "column2"
"column2" + "-" + "column1"

Possible query:
select count(*) from
(   (select distinct column1, column2 from table1) UNION
    (select distinct column2, column1 from table1)    )

I think there is a possible flaw with both queries.

Sample Data :

Column 1          Column 2
Value1            null
null              Value1
Value1            Value2
Value2            Value1
Value4            null
Value5            null

Result for Query 1 : 4 (Value1, Value2, Value4, Value5)
Result for Query 2 : 5 (Value1, Value1-Value2, Value2-Value1, Value4, Value5)

Null is to be ignored with hyphen being excluded. Or hyphen can be ignored. Not particular about the hyphen.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: How could you possibly get a "unique list of **values**" by running a "select **count(*)**? Even if you don't know how to solve your problem, you can't seriously expect a COUNT to give you a LIST OF VALUES.

Comment: Duplicate ref here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11302617/select-distinct-values-from-multiple-columns-in-same-table

Comment: I need a count, not a list of values. I corrected the verbiage.

Comment: I added sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need something similar to this

```
SELECT 
COUNT(DISTINCT [a])

FROM    
(SELECT Column1 [a]
FROM TableA
UNION ALL
SELECT Column2
FROM TableA 

) [x]
```

Comment: Since the result must be de-duplicated in the end anyway, why not simply use `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL`? Then you won't need to count DISTINCT.